# How to migrate magento1 to magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration

I don't know how to migrate from  m1 to m2. How to migrate m1 to m2 steps wise solution tell me? Can you please help me?

Comment: May i know what is your server setup, Nginx or Apache, so that i can help you exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the steps in developer document guide

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Follow every step

and if you stuck in anything here let us know

Answer (score 0):

Magento  uses EAV database structure, so it's very hard to transfer the data manually. You need a script or a tool/extension to do that.

To migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2:

1. Install this data migration tool extension to your Magento 2 store, then perform the migration: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/bk-migration-guide.html
2. Hire a migration service or Magento experts, they will take care of the migration for you.

Don't forget to create a backup before performing the migration.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer Magento doc to learn what are the steps:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

You can avail [Magento migration service](https://cedcommerce.com/magento-services/magento-1-to-magento-2-migration?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=sonker), from one of the best company in eCommerce industry. they will provide you best developer with 24/7 support.